# Loading multiple items from a query into a combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, class, ado.net

I have a WPF form in .Net framework 4.0. What I'm trying to do is to populate a combobox with the results of a query. I can do this but to prevent duplicating code I'm trying to have a class that I can use / call for each combobox I'd like to populate (multiple comboboxes will share results from the same query).

I've constructed my class as below:

```
 internal class DatabaseHandle
    {
        private string _connectionString =
            "Data Source=FINALLYWINDOWS7\\TESTING;Initial Catalog=Testing;Integrated Security=true";

        public string PopulateTeamMembers()
        {
            string queryString = "select    setting_main"
                                 + " from     [marlin].[support_config]"
                                 + " where  config_code = 30"
                                 + "         and setting_active = 1"
                                 + " order by setting_main";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        return reader[0].ToString();
                    }

                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return "Error, unable to load";
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And then in another class I have the following method:

```
private void LoadInterface()
{
    DatabaseHandle testing = new DatabaseHandle();
    string teammembers = testing.PopulateTeamMembers();

    comboBoxResolvedBy.Items.Add(teammembers);
}
```

This populates my combo box except that it only populates it with the first value from the query. I've checked the data, everything is correct on that front but I can't seem to figure out how to enumerate over the query results from the LoadInterface method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that when the function hits the `return` keyword, it exits from your function.
This is why it's only returning one value. It also isn't calling `reader.close`.

You should be returning multiple values in the form of an `IEnumerable<string>`, rather than a `string`.

A way to solve this is to populate a list.

```
    public IEnumerable<string> PopulateTeamMembers()
    {
        List<string> returnList = new List<string>();
        string queryString = "select    setting_main"
                             + " from     [marlin].[support_config]"
                             + " where  config_code = 30"
                             + "         and setting_active = 1"
                             + " order by setting_main";

        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       returnList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
                   }

                   reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Just let the calling class handle the exception
                throw;
            }
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

You can then call it like so:

```
   private void LoadInterface()
   {
       DatabaseHandle testing = new DatabaseHandle();
       IEnumerable<string> teammembers = testing.PopulateTeamMembers();
       foreach(string value in teammembers)
       {
           comboBoxResolvedBy.Items.Add(value);
       }
   }
```

Comment: This is excellent, but sounds like it's maybe not the best way? Can you recommend any subjects I should read up on so I can approach this using a more "industry standard" type approach?

Comment: Also, I'm receiving an error "yield return couldn't appear i nthe try catch block" - Any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, try reading about data access. Using queries like this is not recommended. Also, you can create a string array and keep a reference to it, so you won't have to call this method each time you want a combobox to be populated (in case this list doesn't change very often)

Comment: Also, you should dispose of your reader to release resources.

Comment: OK, I've modified the code - this answer should work now. :-)

Comment: @JonyAdamnit... Aren't we already doing that with reader.close? Is there something more I'm missing?

Comment: @JonyAdamnit - OK, in my example I've added an extra using statement around the SqlDataReader. I'm not sure if this is really needed. Does it just get disposed when the connection is disposed anyway? It's interesting that the MSDN example doesn't use Dispose: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx   Of course, disposing of everything is best practice anyway, so I agree that it is better to wrap it in the using statement.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd, if there's no reference to it, the DataReader will be disposed by the garbage collector.. but you can't rely upon when this will happen and it is not a recommended practice.

Comment: @JonyAdamnit... Thanks! I'll keep that in mind. I'm (clearly) new and this is a learning exercise :)